# Auto-Updating Spreadsheet Range on Google Slides

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-slides-api, google-slides

So I am kind of at an impasse here. I'm designing a menu for a restaurant, that will display on a TV. The menu has a series of sheets, one for each meal period of each day. There is a master sheet which selects the current meal period menu and arrays it. This is all going well, the problem is, when I try to put it on Google Slides so it can be displayed on a TV. I would like the linked sheet in this slide presentation to be auto-updated every 15 minutes, but from what I have read, this is not possible, as the auto-update script only works with charts. Is there anything I can do to get Google Slides to automatically refresh/update the linked Google Sheets range?

Comment: Can I ask you about your situation? I think that the updated content cannot be reflected to the slide under the presentation mode. When the presentation mode is finished, you can see the updated slide. How about this?

Comment: I noticed that you can get fairly good images up to 1600 px wide from the Google Slides API.  So perhaps you could display these images as an html presentation and just update the necessary images every 15 minutes.  No I don't have all the answers to this suggestion.  But perhaps you could run a local web server like IIS and display video from that and then updating the images would be a breeze if you have direct access to the server.   I used to run multimedia presentation with MediaShout and I know we used to change content on the fly without interrupting the video at all. Just a thought